# c function to read digits after card deck in txt file

Tags: c, file

Here's all the code I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char deck[52][3]; //deck declaration

typedef struct cards //declaration of nodes for list
{
  char card[3];
  struct cards * next;
} cards_t;


int main()
{
    int i;


    FILE *fptr;
    fptr = fopen("C:\\Users\\franc\\OneDrive\\Ambiente de Trabalho\\deck.shuffle.txt", "r"); //opens file

    if (fptr == NULL)
        {
            printf("ERROR");
        }

    for (i=0; i<52; i++) //reads deck
        {
            fscanf(fptr, "%s", &deck[i]);
        }

    printf("deck:\n");

    for (i=0; i<52; i++) //prints deck
        {
            printf("%s ", deck[i]);
        }
    printf("\n");

    cards_t * make_list(char **deck); //makes list

    store_seq_digits ();



}



cards_t * make_list(char ** deck) //function to make list
{
   int j = 0;
   cards_t *head = malloc (sizeof(cards_t));

   for (cards_t * iterator = head; j<52; iterator = iterator->next, j++)
   {
      strcpy(iterator->card, deck[j]);
      iterator->next = malloc(sizeof(cards_t));
   }

   return head;
}


store_seq_digits (char seq[]) //function to read, store and print digits after deck
    {
        FILE *fptr;
        fptr = fopen("C:\\Users\\franc\\OneDrive\\Ambiente de Trabalho\\deck.shuffle.txt", "r");
        int n;
        int i;
        char *array;
        array = (char*) malloc(n * sizeof(char));

        for (i=52; i<n; i++)
            {
                fscanf(fptr, "%c", &array[i]);
            }
        for (i=0; i<n; i++)
            {
                printf("%c ", array[i]);
            }
        fclose(fptr);
    }
```

Note that the txt file is a full card deck with digits at the end of it, something like (example):

- AS 2S 3S 4S 5S 6S 7S 8S 9S TS JS QS KS ... JC QC KC 1 2 3 2 1

(S = spades, C = clubs, etc)

The number of digits is arbitrary, and thus the size of the array I want to store them in is unknown.

What I want is to read, store, and print those digits as ints, not chars.

When it runs, it only prints the deck, and nothing else. Any help?

Comment: Do you know the number of cards in the text file? I mean, is it always 52?

Comment: @MiradilZeynalli yes, always. what is unknown is the size of those digits, it can vary depending of what is written in the file before the program runs

Comment: `int n; array = (char*) malloc(n * sizeof(char));` The `n` is not initialised.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not know the exact number of incoming elements (be it buffer, file or anything else), you can use the return value of `scanf`. Create a large array (so that, it never overflows) and read each element into the array.

```
int values[100]; // assuming that there are always less than 100 numbers

int store_seq_digits (FILE *f) // use already opened file pointer, no need to skip all 52 cards again.
{
    int i = 0;

    while(fscanf(f, "%d", &values[i++]) == 1); // while there is smth to scan, scan into array

    return i; // return number of elements
}
```

So, in main, you use `int n = store_seq_digits(fptr)`.